# Symfony2 Unit Testing Bundle Extension::load()

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony

Does anyone have any tips for unit testing `Extension::load()` method?

It seems like this function isn't designed to handle unit testing since we hard-code the path(s) for it to load.

Any ideas?